# Unix command to search pattern at a specific position and delete the lines matching those patterns

Tags: shell, unix

I want to perform the following operations using unix command
1. Delete lines that start with ! in the 1st position and have the patterns ABCD and XYZ starting at 10th position. 
2. Delete lines that start with ! and match the pattern QRST in the 10th position. In this case. it should also delete the next line only if it starts with the number 1

Example:

```
!        ABCD toberemoved
!        XYZ  toberemoved
         ABCD validdataABCDtest
         1234 XYZ1234validdata
!        QRST Secondscenariotoberemoved
1        1234 678900toberemoved
```

Expected Result:

```
 ABCD validdataABCDtest
 1234 XYZ1234
```

Comment: What have you tried? Contrary to what you seem to believe, StackOverflow isn't a free coding service (or exam answering service). You're expected to show your code, along with relevant sample inputs, expected outputs, actual error msgs as well as your comments about where you are stuck. Please show your best effort to solve this problem (use the {} tool at the top left of the edit box to format code/data/output/errMsgs correctly), and people may be able to help you. . . .

Comment: Please read  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask ,  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  and take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) before posting more Qs here. 
Good luck.